# Assembling ARM computer

Tags: arm, arm7, arm9

I want to assemble my own mini-computer with ARM processor, but I don't know the start point I must to start.

Can you advice me some articles or other sources where I can read something about that?

EDIT: I want to assemble computer with ~500-700 MHz CPU freq, 128-256 MBytes operational memory, ethernet, wifi, VGA

EDIT: Now I am a bachelor in IT, and programming is the best I can. In hardware I does not know so much. In university I've listen several courses like Computer (CPU) Architecture, Disctrete Math and other like this.

I want to replace my annoying home proxy-server with that computer to decrease noise and energy consumption, and it is also interesting :)

Comment: Which ARM? There are zillions of them. What do you want it for? What's the required performance? What subsystems do you need? etc, etc.. Which means: this question can't be properly answered in its current form and will likely be closed.

Comment: I need a general knowledge about that. Also, see EDIT

Comment: @skayred A good starting point would be to add to the question what you already know. What you're asking right now is worth a couple of years of studying at a good university.

Comment: What do you want to do with it?

Comment: I've added some info into the question

Comment: If you simply need a ARM server, there are a few you can buy off the shelf. Take a look at the GutuPlug server http://www.globalscaletechnologies.com/p-31-guruplug-server-standard.aspx

Comment: You might want to look at the beagle board to get an idea of what others have done.

Comment: What you want to do is actually rather difficult even for a seasoned PCB designer. At such speeds you need to start worrying about trace lengths and transmission line effects. It is likely that you will have to use a BGA component, which means four or more layers at least, and PCB's like that are very expensive (100$+ at absolute least). Now, if you want to do it for fun as a super long project, you can. For what ARM cpu, you do not want to go BGA since that is too complicated to use for you. There was a website for this, but I can't find it now. I will put it here when I do find it. :P

Comment: In case you were not really wanting to design your own board, but instead assemble an arm based computer.  There are a number of platforms out there that can do what you want.  raspberry pi, hawkboard, beaglebone, beagleboard, pandaboard, open-rd to name a few

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that as a beginner.

It's more realistic to split it into two parts:

- Buy a suitable small ARM computer for the server (for example a Beagleboard).
- Tinker with microcontrollers to learn about hardware.

Comment: Thanks. But can you recommend some literature to getting started with that? I mean microcontroller and, in future, working with ARM